# Suspend and Resume in POSIX thread

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I am learning POSIX threads. My question - How to suspend and resume pthread ? Like threads in Java, is there any function like wait, notify etc? I want to run the single pthread multiple times according to some situations.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468333/linux-threads-suspend-resume This might have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> How to suspend and resume pthread ? Like threads in Java, is there any
>   function like wait, notify etc?

Read about conditional variables in [pthread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads). Basically, conditional variables allow you to check for a condition before a thread can proceed further. Say for example there are 3 threads which will only proceed if some condition is true. In case, this condition is false, the threads will release the mutex lock they are holding and "wait". As the lock on the shared object of type `pthread_mutex_t` is released, some other thread(s) will go ahead and do their stuff thus at some point in time the condition will become true (hopefully). Check the function called `pthread_cond_wait`.

Once the said condition becomes true (or is satisfied), then the functions `pthread_cond_signal` / `pthread_cond_broadcast` could be used to "notify" the threads which were waiting on the `pthread_cond_t` object. These threads (3 threads in this simple explanation) then acquire the mutex lock automatically (of course, one thread at a time) and go about their business.

Check [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) tutorial.

> I want to run the single pthread multiple times according to some
>   situations.

Care to explain further?